# Create RegEx to only select on alphabet and number e.g. A1

Tags: regex

I need an expression which will only select a specific type of string. For example in the string:

```
C5 1A IDX FUTI
IDX C3 FUTI D2
```

I only want it to select `C5`, `C3` and `D2`

Comment: To clarify, you need matches that are a letter and a number? This seems too simple... Have you looked at a regex tester like [RegexR](https://regexr.com/) or [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: Yes a Caps letter and a number.

Comment: `[A-Z][0-9]` ? Just this?

Comment: Try one of the regex testers and make an attempt. Edit your question if you get stuck after that. Here's a start for you... Capital Letters: `[A-Z]`, Number: `[0-9]` or `\d`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
\b[A-Z]\d\b
```

might work OK then.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K0U1fH/1/)